# Import and rearrange txt file

Tags: text

I have a txt file like this:

```
A   B C
400 2 3
2   1 8
```

Now I would like to import the txt file and write it all on one line instead of in columns, so like that:

```
A B C 400 2 3 2 1 8
```

How can I achieve this with *Mathematica* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringRiffle[ReadList["C:/temp/temp.txt", Word], " "]
```

Comment: This is great ! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Alan, if the input txt is: ABC 123 BCD 234 EFG 345,output I need is 123 234 345, how can I do in MMA?

Comment: New questions should be created as a new question.  Anyway, the Mma documentation for `ReadList` and `Part` are excellent; start there.  E.g., `ReadList[StringToStream@"ABC 123 BCD 234 EFG 345", {Word, Number}][[All,2]]`.